# Returning a pointer address from a function in C

Tags: c, pointers

FIXED: Issue was with the recursion not the pointers. When it returned back through each recursion it would reset the returned VAR to the old maintree. Fixed by making a global VAR and set it before return then made whole function return void. No memory leaks.

I am trying to pass a malloc'd pointer address to a pointer variable in main().

The code works up to a point. Instead of passing the pointer address from FinalTree back to main, it creates a new copy which means I am unable to free() the memory that was malloc'd in FinalTree(). When I do a memory check I am left with some non freed memory.

Here is the code so far:

```
Tree* FinalTree(Forest** forest, int FinalFreq)
{

    Tree* maintree = mktree(); //this function calls malloc and have to use it
    Tree* tree1 = pick(*forest);
    Tree* tree2 = pick(*forest);

    maintree->frequency = tree1->frequency + tree2->frequency;
    maintree->left = tree1;
    maintree->right = tree2;

    //Make sure forest isnt barren
    if (maintree->frequency != FinalFreq)
    {
        plant(*forest, maintree);
        FinalTree(forest, FinalFreq);
    }

    return maintree;
}
```

This is called from main() by:

```
Tree* tfinal = FinalTree(&finit, header.checksum);
```

Pointers are driving me nuts.. What am I missing?

Comment: Basically it just adds the node back into the list. The project is to 'uncompress' a file made by a Huffman tree. This is just rebuilding the tree from the compressed file. The free function for the forest clears ALL nodes in the forest. Valgrind is saying there is only 1 block not being freed and I have traced it to the returned maintree var.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. It seems to me like the problem is the recursive call to `FinalTree`, whose return address you don't save anywhere, and therefore can't `free()`, is that correct?

Comment: Thats basically it.. I want to return the actual 'chunk' of memory (or address of that chunk). At the end of the recursive calls, I just be left with one top tree with multiple leafs off of that top one.

Comment: And @JorgeIsraelPeña pointed out the problem: FinalTree which you are calling returns a pointer to a newly allocated Tree element which you simply dismiss. And that's where the memoryleak comes from. I also think it doesn't make sense to dismiss the returned pointer as it could be different of forest and maintree.

Comment: That's my issue if I am reading this right. I don't want to dismiss the returned pointer. I want it to become tfinal in main (where FinalTree() is called from) so I can free it after I am done with it in main();

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me if I don't understand your question completely, but based off the comment I think I have an idea what you're referring to now.

That function creates the tree, but only returns the top level root node's address. Your problem is that if you `free()` that one, the rest of the tree is still allocated, correct? If so, I think that the solution to this is to write a dedicated `FreeTree(Tree *)` function which traverses the tree and `free()`'s the individual leaf nodes on the way back up.

Something like (not tested):

```
void FreeTree(Tree *tree) {
  if (tree == NULL)
    return;

  FreeTree(tree->left);
  FreeTree(tree->right);
  free(tree);                                                                                                            
}
```

**Update**: Ah okay. That is indeed weird. I don't see anything in the function that would alter the `maintree` aside from `mktree()` which creates it. Unless `plant` takes a reference to a pointer:

```
void plant(Forest forest, Tree *&tree)
```

Then `plant()` could modify the pointer `maintree` points to. Otherwise it does look like it should be returning the root node.

Comment: I guess I am not explaining it right. I already have a function that will free() the top node and ALL nodes underneath. (It was actually already supplied to us. What seems to the issues is that tFinal in main() is not pointing to the chunk that was malloc'd for maintree.

Comment: The proto for plant is bool plant(Forest* f, Tree* t);

Comment: Yeah to be honest I'm at a loss. The pointer returned by main's call to `FinalTree()` should indeed return the root node's pointer, it seems to me. Passing this pointer to your dedicated tree freeing function should correctly delete the entire tree. Is there any chance there's more code than you pasted involved in that function? Also, could you please elaborate on how it is you're experiencing the issue, from main's perspective? (i.e. in main, the code you use to call `FinalTree()` as well as your code to free it, and how it is you conclude that it's a copy and not the original)

Comment: Give me a couple of mins.. I think I might have found the issue just need to run debug a couple more times to confirm.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. The issue was with the recursive function.. Each time it returned it changed the the address to the previous recursion. My fix was to create a global variable then at the last recursion set it to that and just have the whole function return void. Thanks all. Wasn't a pointer issue at all.